# Help with dual monitor support with Gnome

Tags: gnome, ati, multiple-monitors

I just recently got Gnome because I got tired of Unity. The way I have my monitors set up is as follows. I have one 1080p monitor on the bottom and a 900p monitor on top. I want to be able to have the 1080p monitor as the main one, but if I select the bottom one as the main, I am not able to drag programs from the bottom one to the top. If I set the top one as the main monitor, I can't move games or other full screen processes down to the 1080p monitor. Could someone please help me out with this problem? Thanks.
PS I have a Radeon HD 6870